# Add Sharepoint Online list item using pure JavaScript

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, sharepoint-rest-api

I am trying to do the following:

I have a Wordpress site where I have created a form. On `submit` event I want to send the data to my Sharepoint Online list. The problem I am facing is the fact that the solution needs to be build entirely with JavaScript and/or jQuery.

I have seen multiple examples of people doing it but all of them somehow are having `client context` or `_spPageContextInfo` available. That is not the case with me.

My question is: **Is there a way just send the data to the list using simple `POST` request?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OutSide of SharePoint Online Site, it's necessary to get the access token for authentication purpose.

A solution is to register a SharePoint App and get the access token with this request:

[image]

[image]

Then use the access token in the request to handle data:

[image]

Here is a detailed blog for reference:

[Accessing SharePoint Data using Postman (SharePoint REST API)](https://medium.com/@anoopt/accessing-sharepoint-data-using-postman-sharepoint-rest-api-76b70630bcbf)

Postman is a test purpose, you can convert the request above into Jquery ajax for coding.

Comment: I see! Just a quick question: Is this token will ever expire?

Comment: Yes, the access token will expire in 12 hours. please check the details in this blog:
https://spshell.blogspot.com/2015/03/sharepoint-online-o365-oauth.html

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion it helped me figure out my problem!